# Is it possible to prevent specific backups from being deleted?

Tags: time-machine

I develop on a Mac and want to use Time Machine to move between different versions of OSX so that I can use different versions of Xcode to support older iOS versions. The idea being that, in a few years, I'll have a suite of backups for different versions of OSX and I can choose to go back or forward as development needs require.

(For instance right now I'm creating a backup of Yosemite before upgrading to El Capitan, and then I'll take an El Capitan backup)

Right now Time Machine is taking a backup every hour, and it states that the oldest backups will be deleted once the drive is full. What I would like to do is continue taking regular backups, but to be able to flag specific backups to never be deleted. The goal being to continue to have protection again a disk failure or accident, but to never lose my 'special' OS-version specific backups.

Comment: tbh, what I'd do is have a boot drive for each & a Time Machine for each. Swap both at the same time, every time.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm very new to Macs, how do you go about creating multiple boot drives? Does Apple provide an ISO for each OSX version?

Comment: No, you need to already have the OS installers, or at least have previously 'purchased' them through your Apple ID [otherwise you need to find a friend who can access them] & make a [bootable installer](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372) If you have a Mac Pro, simplest is to just dedicate a drive to each, or partition & install one to each. Same for Time Machine, just swap the drive out each time. If you don't have a Mac Pro, you can do the same with external USB/Firewire/Thunderbolt drives.

Comment: An alternative might be - start with the oldest OS you need to work with; install to drive/partition; set up as desired; clone to new partition, update to next OS; clone; update. Then at least the setup would be minimal for the newer OSes. I'd still keep a separate TM for each, though. Cross-pollination wouldn't be good.

Comment: @Tetsujin Since Yosemite is no longer in the app store I take it there is no official way to get that installer any more, right?

Comment: Not if you don't already 'own' it.